# How do I upgrade an RHEL machine to a newer, but not the newest, point release?

Tags: centos, redhat, yum

Let's say I've got an RHEL machine that is running RHEL5.4.  I'd like to upgrade it to 5.7 (latest), but the vendor that makes the software sitting on the machine only certifies it to 5.6.  How can I upgrade to 5.6 but make sure I don't end up in 5.7 land?  I'm sure I'm missing something basic here, but I can't find it.

Same question applies to CentOS, I suppose, so if someone has an answer there I'd try it.

Comment: Vendor needs to hustle to certify 5.7.

Comment: Agreed.  Doesn't help in this case :)

Comment: Vendor == the combination of Oracle and NetApp (using SnapManager for Oracle), for the record. Still no 5.7 or 6 support :(

Comment: They changed it so they only support 5.5 with our stack, 5.6 is too new :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that in the RedHat online control panel you can lock a machine to a given version.  How did I miss that?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in centos.. In Redhat I'm sure you can get one from a disc or online somewhere..

You can install the correct release rpm and set yum to ignore installing updates

```
rpm -q centos-release
```

So if that is the current version you want to keep.. Then you can add

```
exclude=centos-release*
```

to your /etc/yum.conf file and it will never go to the next higher version of centos. The process would be similar in redhat land but the package is called

```
redhat-release-5Server
```

Like i found it here

http://mirror.corbina.net/pub/Linux/redhat/rpms/x64/

Install at your own risk since it isn't an official repository. That repo is for 5.6. It has the same version for the release rpm as my redhat 5.6 servers.

Comment: Hm.  Any idea how I would upgrade to an intermediate version?  i.e. from 5.4 to 5.6, but not 5.7?

Comment: that last link in my post has the rpm for redhat-release-5Server install that then set the exclude in yum.conf and do a yum update and you'll be locked to 5.6

Answer (score 2):

There is no forced upgrade in RHEL/Centos land (unlike say Ubuntu where it will prompt you constantly) you can just use the 5.6 media / repos to upgrade and then it won't magically upgrade to 5.7 unless you repeat the same procedure for 5.7

Comment: Yes, damn those Ubuntu people for notifying people of uninstalled security updates.

Comment: i'm not talking about security updates, but distro upgrades, they arn't the same thing.

Comment: Ubuntu hassles you when you're running anything other than the latest release?  Even when the version you're running is still supported?

Comment: yep, it'll ask you to do distro upgrades if it exists at least the last time I was on an old version

Comment: How does it do the prompting?  motd every time you SSH in?

Comment: nah when you run apt-get update ... "there is a new version available ... do blah blah blah to upgrade"

Comment: /me adds one more entry to the "why I don't use Ubuntu" list

Comment: But how do I install 5.6 security updates without rolling to 5.7, once 5.7 is out?  The RPMs on the 5.6 disk aren't the last updates for 5.6...

Comment: @bill rhel/centos only instally updates for the version you are running. It will never upgrade your release without you explicitly doing so

Comment: Hm.  I seem to be doing something wrong, then. I have a machine that upgraded from 5.5 to 5.7 with a "yum update"...

Comment: Yep, I had it happen again. I can't figure out any way to do this other than only letting it install from the media, which obviously means no security updates. Hmm